# Iterate different value with same key json

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is my array

```
[{"option":"27 : 28","image":""},{"option":"20 : 25","image":""},{"option":"28 : 27 ","image":""},{"option":"25 : 20","image":""}]
```

These are four option how can i echo them

Expectation

```
A=27:28               B=20:25              C=28:27              D=25:20
```

Comment: Please read how to ask questions with a `Minimal, Reproducible Example`: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please help me to echo this as per my expectations

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```php
$letter = 'A';
$arr = json_decode('[{"option":"27 : 28","image":""},{"option":"20 : 25","image":""},{"option":"28 : 27 ","image":""},{"option":"25 : 20","image":""}]', 1);

foreach($arr as $a) {
    echo $letter++ . '=' . $a['option'] . '<br/>' ;
}
```